# How can I check all data in loop before save into database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

Now in my Controller it looks like this

```
assume that $available = [ 1,2,3,4 ]

    for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
      if($available < 3){
        echo 'success';
        $database->save();
      }else{
        echo 'error';
      }
    }
```

this will output  like success success success error

and it will save 3 success into database , how can I check if I've 1 error it won't save any data?

Now I'm using

```
   $errors = false;
    DB::transaction(function () use ($count,$request,$a,$errors) {
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $warehouse_products_sell = New Warehouse_products_sell;
            $id_w = $request->input('idw');
            $id_c = $request->get('id_c')[$i];
            $id_p = $request->get('id_p')[$i];
            $qty = $request->input('quantity_box')[$i];
            $price = $request->input('price')[$i];
            $available = $this->check_stock($id_w, $id_p, $qty);
          if($available > 0){
            $warehouse_products_sell->add_by = $request->input('add_by');

            $warehouse_products_sell->id_w = $id_w = $request->input('idw');
            $warehouse_products_sell->id_c = $request->get('id_c')[$i];
            $warehouse_products_sell->id_p = $id_p = $request->get('id_p')[$i];
            $warehouse_products_sell->quantity_box = $qty = $request->input('quantity_box')[$i];
            $warehouse_products_sell->price = $request->input('price')[$i];
            $warehouse_products_sell->serial_num = $a;
            $available = $this->check_stock($id_w, $id_p, $qty);
            $warehouse_products_sell->save();
          }else{

            echo "error";
            $errors = true;

            throw new Exception('Error');
          }
        }
    });
    if ($errors) {
       return redirect('URL');
    }else{
        return 'x';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Transactions. Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#database-transactions).

Your code will change to this

```php
DB::transaction(function () use ($database, $available) {
    for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
      if($available < 3){
        echo 'success';
        $database->save();
      }else{
        echo 'error';
        throw new \Exception('Error');
      }
    }
});
```

If any exception is thrown, it will automatically rollback.

---

Adding redirect if any problem arrise

```php
$errors = false;

DB::transaction(function () use ($database, $available, $errors) {
    for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) {
      if($available < 3){
        echo 'success';
        $database->save();
      }else{
        echo 'error';
        $errors = true;
        throw new \Exception('Error');
      }
    }
});

if ($errors) {
  return redirect('URL');
}
```

Comment: thnks sir i nv know this before =]

Comment: is their anyway to  redirect route or return page after throw exception

Comment: no, because when you do that, the `function` (transaction) will catch that exception and rollback. What you can do is pass a variable on the `use` and if there is any error, change that to false or anything it flags you as an error, and when out of transaction, read that variable and then redirect.

Comment: I updated my answer. I am doing this by memory, so sorry if there is any PHP error.

Comment: it stop at throw new \Exception('Error');  if($errors) didnt working i echo $errors before if($errors) it return noting

Comment: I see that in your real code, you are using `$request`, remember to pass that variable on the `use`, because it will not be available. And don't do `echo $errors`, because it is a bool, you will see nothing, instead do `var_dump($errors);`

Comment: sorry i forget to update my code now everything work fine except if($errors) loop , if ive an error it still not redirect  my code it stop at else{ throw new Exception('Error'); }

Comment: every thing that below this line throw new \Exception('Error'); are not working

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you have to pass the `$errors` variable as a reference and not as value, like this `use(&$errors)`, but I am not sure.

Comment: ok sir ill take a break first haha thank you for helping me a lot

Comment: if it not working may be ill looking for try {} catch {}